# AWS AppSync in node environment spews errors about asyncLocalStorage when configured per example

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Following [the example provided in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-javascript.html) I find the following message repeated many times in the logs:

> redux-persist asyncLocalStorage requires a global localStorage object. Either use a different storage backend or if this is a universal redux application you probably should conditionally persist like so: https://gist.github.com/rt2zz/ac9eb396793f95ff3c3b

I can work around it by turning off offline support when creating the AppSync client, like this:

```
new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: 'https://...appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql',
  region: 'us-west-2',
  auth: {
    type: 'AWS_IAM',
    credentials: ...
  },
  disableOffline: true
})
```

... however I do want to use the offline store. I am using the setup config from the documentation like so:

```
global.WebSocket = require('ws');
global.window = global.window || {
    setTimeout: setTimeout,
    clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
    WebSocket: global.WebSocket,
    ArrayBuffer: global.ArrayBuffer,
    addEventListener: function () { },
    navigator: { onLine: true }
};
global.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    getItem: function (key) {
        return this.store[key]
    },
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        this.store[key] = value
    },
    removeItem: function (key) {
        delete this.store[key]
    }
};
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
```

But it doesn't seem to work with `redux-persist` which is used a few layers deep in the AppSync client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a very simple way to resolve this issue. While this section is taken directly from the AWS docs it is not quite right:

```
global.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    ...
};
```

By setting `global.window.localStorage` instead I am able to work around the issues:

```
global.window.localStorage = {
    store: {},
    ...
};
```

---

Anyone else trying to use AppSync like this may want to know that `node-localstorage` also seems to work with this usage (after `yarn add node-localstorage`):

```
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage
global.window.localStorage = new LocalStorage(<path for storage>)
```

Importantly, in this case, your queries are persisted to the file system and will be read if connectivity is lost. This could potentially work after restarting your application (but I've not tested this yet because you need an AWS credentials object to create the AppSync client).

Comment: Thank you very much for your good info. Maybe can you explain what they are doing with this configuration pls? Are they setting up something to global to make the node.js client as web browser? or in order to make offline working?

Comment: I'm not completely certain but, yes, like you say I believe this is backfilling stuff that Apollo expects to be present (because Apollo is targeted at browsers/webapps) but in a nodejs environment those things are missing. I've not found this to work terribly well to be honest (though I'm sure it can be done); I ended up just building a simple offline cache and doing all queries online.

Comment: Thanks for your updating @macbutch !
I think it will be better for us to use Amplify/API category since it also supports GraphQL and AppSync gracefully.
So we can avoid this overhead we are not sure what it's doing for.